# Is there any plugin for logging joomla errors and warnings like drupal

Tags: joomla, error-logging

Is there any plugin for logging joomla errors and warnings like drupal (reports-> recent log messages). I would really appreciate if something like that extension exist. I searched in extensions but I got not suitable extension. Plz help

Answer (score 0):

Try these Joomla extensions.

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/administration/admin-reports/24395?qh=YTo1OntpOjA7czozOiJsb2ciO2k6MTtzOjY6ImxvZ2dlZCI7aToyO3M6NzoibG9nZ2luZyI7aTozO3M6NDoibG9ncyI7aTo0O3M6NzoiJ2xvZ2dlZCI7fQ%3D%3D

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/administration/admin-reports/19118?qh=YTo1OntpOjA7czozOiJsb2ciO2k6MTtzOjY6ImxvZ2dlZCI7aToyO3M6NzoibG9nZ2luZyI7aTozO3M6NDoibG9ncyI7aTo0O3M6NzoiJ2xvZ2dlZCI7fQ%3D%3D

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/miscellaneous/development/23514

Comment: Yes, I have already gone through this extensions, but none of this are as compared to drupal log except loggie and loggie also keep popping warning message to disable itself.

Comment: but loggie's behaviour is correct: excessive logging slows down your site so it's nice of it to warn you. If you don't like the warnings, edit them out of the code.